# What is the || characters stands for in Javascript? Actually i used it with Nodejs and Passport

Tags: javascript, node.js

Sorry if my question is silly, but i didn't find any sufficient answer on this.

I was creating a Facebook login just for training in my personal page. Studying on Internet i found that i need to provide some Facebook info like:

```
clientID: process.env.CLIENT_ID
```

So, i supposed that it would be (e.g)

```
clientID: process.env.8483843285375325blabla
```

But after struggling for a while, i figured out that the proper way was

```
    clientID: process.env.CLIENT_ID || '8483843285375325blabla'
```

So what the || stands for? When we use it? I have used it as an OR logical operator in other programming languages.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

|| is the Javascript OR logical operator. This line:

```
clientID: process.env.CLIENT_ID || '8483843285375325blabla'
```

Can be read as: `clientId` attribute will be assigned the value of `process.env.CLIENT_ID` if logically true or '8483843285375325blabla'. So if `process.env.CLIENT_ID` is not set or set to false then `'8483843285375325blabla'` will be used.

Answer (score 3):

That is a normal [`logical or operator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators). But its usage is different at your context. It will start evaluate from left to right and whenever it faces a truthy value, it will break and return the detected truthy value.

```
var x = null || 0 || undefined || "" || "bringHimHome";
console.log(x) //bringHimHome
```

Consider the above code from left to right, all are falsy values, so it will evaluates one by one up to the last string and it will return that final string value as it is truthy.

Answer (score 1):

`||` is an logical or. [Logical Operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators)

> Returns `expr1` if it can be converted to `true`; otherwise, returns `expr2`. Thus, when used with Boolean values, || returns `true` if either operand can be converted to `true`; if both can be converted to `false`, returns `false`.